# Error with grunt (grunt-contrib)

Tags: gruntjs, npm

If I want to install a package via npm globally, then I get the following error repeatedly... Has anybody an idea to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Which version are you trying to install? Looks like you already have a grunt-contrib-compress at a version which the current package, you want to install, is not happy with.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is don't install `grunt-contrib`. It used to be a small collection of tasks but as the `grunt-contrib-*` series grew, so did that library.

Nobody ever needs to install every `grunt-contrib-*` library. Instead, just install the tasks you need: `npm install grunt-contrib-compress --save-dev`

Otherwise, if you insist, install the peer dependency version it expects `npm install grunt-contrib-compress@0.6.1` and try installing again: `npm install grunt-contrib`.